# Microsoft Forms Loading Loop

Tags: microsoft, microsoft-forms

WHen I am using microsoft forms with my work account. I can log into forms and get the home page loading correctly.

However when I try and open any form, Microsoft gets stuck in a refresh loop that I am unable to get out of

This is for every form.

I have tried clearing browsing data as well as deleting some local files recommended on Microsoft forums.

Does anyone have a fix or have encountered this issue before?